# Unable to remove stale volume

Tags: lvm, usb-drive, luks, cryptsetup, volume

I have an external hard drive connected to my Ubuntu laptop via USB. The whole hard drive is LUKS encrypted. Next to the encryption layer sits an LVM volume which I mount to `/mnt/es`. Once opened, `lsblk` sees it all as:

```
sdc                                          8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk  
└─es (dm-6)                                252:6    0   2.7T  0 crypt 
  └─externalstorage-externalstorage (dm-7) 252:7    0   2.7T  0 lvm   /mnt/es
```

Sometimes somehow the hard drive gets "detached" from the volumes, in which case the data becomes inaccessible:

```
sdc                                        8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk  
es (dm-6)                                252:6    0   2.7T  0 crypt 
└─externalstorage-externalstorage (dm-7) 252:7    0   2.7T  0 lvm
```

I noted that it typically happens when the laptop goes to sleep.

Now, the problem is that once `sdc` has [been?] detached, I cannot get rid of the two stale volumes `es` and `externalstorage-externalstorage` in order to reuse their names again. The first thing I do is `umount /mnt/es` which goes fine. But then, even though the volume is not mounted, I cannot remove it:

```
dmsetup remove --force /dev/mapper/externalstorage-externalstorage
device-mapper: resume ioctl on externalstorage-externalstorage failed: Invalid argument
device-mapper: remove ioctl on externalstorage-externalstorage failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

The `info` command shows that the volume is opened:

```
dmsetup info -c /dev/mapper/externalstorage-externalstorage
Name                            Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID                                                                
externalstorage-externalstorage 252   7 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-R4bAWzxJ8Cy3MBIjmPps60Rd3cFVyBStxTeKaR6gBHdefTYfJNWhHfA8tzqOBHns
```

Here is what seems to be holding the volume but it does not tell me much:

```
fuser -m /dev/mapper/externalstorage-externalstorage
Cannot stat file /proc/5687/fd/4: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/5687/fd/5: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/5687/fd/6: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/5687/fd/7: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/5687/fd/11: Stale file handle
```

From LVM point of view it is not accessible either:

```
pvdisplay
  /dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2981780979712: Input/output error
  /dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2981781037056: Input/output error
  /dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
```

Interestingly, at this point, `cryptsetup luksClose es` can be repeated any number of times without any visible impact or error message.

So how can I get rid of those stale volumes (apart from rebooting)? And is there any way to prevent the problem happening in the first place, i.e. why does `sdc` detach now and again?

[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, kernel 3.19.0-42-generic]

**Update**

`vgchange -an` yields similar errors as above:

```
/dev/mapper/es: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 3000590794752: Input/output error
/dev/mapper/es: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 3000590876672: Input/output error
/dev/mapper/es: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/mapper/es: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
/dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2981780979712: Input/output error
/dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 2981781037056: Input/output error
/dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/externalstorage/externalstorage: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
```

Answer (score 4):

It's more like a guesswork, but it looks like you will need to deactive the lvm before you can remove the crypt mapping, basically working your way back out from the inside:

First, you'll need to umount any stale fs on the lvm:

```
umount -f /mnt/es
```

Then deactivate the lvm that you appear to have *on top* of cryptsetup.  Even if you have other vgs, the following should deactivate anything it can, without harming the system if it using any other vg:

```
vgchange -an
```

After this, you can use dmsetup to remove the mapping created by cryptsetup(!)

```
dmsetup remove externalstorage
```

(I may have mistook some of the names, feel free to correct it)

It seems the basic problem that during sleep, your USB drive is dropping off the bus, and when it comes back, the block system finds that sdb disappeared, though there is an sdc now.

Comment: Thanks for your input but `vgchange -an` yields the same sort of "Input/output error" errors as `pvdisplay` (shown in the question).

Comment: I had a different problem, but `dmsetup` was the answer

Answer (score 2):

1. Close all users of the device and backup device data as needed.
2. Use `umount` to unmount any file systems that mounted the device.
3. Remove the device from any md and LVM volume using it. If the device is a member of an LVM Volume group, then it may be necessary to move data off the device using the pvmove command, then use the `vgreduce` command to remove the physical volume, and (optionally) `pvremove` to remove the LVM metadata from the disk.
4. If the device uses multipathing, run `multipath -l` and note all the paths to the device. Afterwards, remove the multipathed device using `multipath -f device`.
5. Run `blockdev --flushbufs` device to flush any outstanding I/O to all paths to the device. This is particularly important for raw devices, where there is no umount or vgreduce operation to cause an I/O flush.
6. Remove any reference to the device's path-based name, like `/dev/sd`, `/dev/disk/by-path` or the `major:minor` number, in applications, scripts, or utilities on the system. This is important in ensuring that different devices added in the future will not be mistaken for the current device.
7. Finally, remove each path to the device from the SCSI subsystem. To do so, use the command `echo 1 > /sys/block/device-name/device/delete` where device-name may be `sde`, for example.
   Another variation of this operation is `echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/h:c:t:l/device/delete`, where `h` is the HBA number, `c` is the channel on the HBA, `t` is the SCSI target ID, and `l` is the LUN.

For more details refer [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/online_storage_reconfiguration_guide/removing_devices)!

Also you can use `sg_utils` script to remove stale volume using [rescan-scsi-bus.sh](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/online_storage_reconfiguration_guide/rescan-scsi-bus)!